# How to merge array of hashes with same keys in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashtable

I have an array of items like this:

```
items = [{name: 'item_1', qty: 1, unit_price: 5},
{name: 'item_1', qty: 2, unit_price: 5},
{name: 'item_2', qty: 3, unit_price: 10},
{name: 'item_2', qty: 2, unit_price: 10}]
```

I want to combine items with the same name into one hash by summing up the quantities. The expected output for the above example should be:

```
[{name: 'item_1', qty: 3, unit_price: 5},
{name: 'item_2', qty: 5, unit_price: 10}]
```

Comment: Why unit price of item2 in output is different?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The reason this question is getting downvoted is because you're not displaying any kind of attempt at solving the problem. Asking other people to complete a task as if they were assigned it in the first place is seen as rude and the community doesn't generally like "Gimme dah codez" questions. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @mechnicov these are not the actual data. I just wrote an example similar to the actual one. Anyway I fixed that.

Comment: @max, thanks for the advice. To be honest, I posted this as a question after trying for hours. Anyway, I will post some of my attempts on my next questions.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the unit price is always the same for the same name? Lets say you have `{name: 'item_2', qty: 3, unit_price: 7 },
  {name: 'item_2', qty: 2, unit_price: 10}`. You can't just sum that up to `{name: 'item_2', qty: 5, unit_price: 10}`.

Comment: I made a correction to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = [
  {name: 'item_1', qty: 1, unit_price: 5},
  {name: 'item_1', qty: 2, unit_price: 5},
  {name: 'item_2', qty: 3, unit_price: 10},
  {name: 'item_2', qty: 2, unit_price: 10}
]
```

```
items.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:name]=>g) { |_k,o,n| o.merge(qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty]) }
end.values
  [{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5},
   {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>5, :unit_price=>10}]
```

---

This uses the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (`{ |_k,o,n| o.merge(qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty]) }`)to compute the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

`g[:name]=>g`, when it appears as an argument (as here), is shorthand for (and equivalent to) `{ g[:name]=>g }`. The name of the block variable `_k`, which holds the common key, begins with an underscore to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation. It is common for such a block variable to be represented as simply `_` (a valid name for a local variable).

`items` is not mutated.

---

We can add some `puts` statements to examine the calculations for the example.

```
items.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  puts "h = #{h}"
  puts "g = #{g}"
  puts "g[:name]=>g = #{g[:name]}=>#{g}"
  h.update(g[:name]=>g) do |_k,o,n|
    puts "Defer to block to calc value of key #{_k}"
    puts "o = #{o}"
    puts "n = #{n}"
    puts "{ qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty] } = #{{ qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty] }}"
    f = o.merge(qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty])
    puts "o.merge(qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty]) = #{f}"
    f
  end
  puts
end.tap do |h|
  puts "Value of h returned = #{h}"
  puts "h.values = #{h.values}"
end.
values
  #=> [{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5},
  #    {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>5, :unit_price=>10}]
```

The following is printed (with some hand reformatting).

```
h = {}
g = {:name=>"item_1", :qty=>1, :unit_price=>5}
g[:name]=>g = item_1=>{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>1, :unit_price=>5}

h = {"item_1"=>{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>1, :unit_price=>5}}
g = {:name=>"item_1", :qty=>2, :unit_price=>5}
g[:name]=>g = item_1=>{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>2, :unit_price=>5}
Defer to block to calc value of key item_1
o = {:name=>"item_1", :qty=>1, :unit_price=>5}
n = {:name=>"item_1", :qty=>2, :unit_price=>5}
{ qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty] } = {:qty=>3}
o.merge(qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty]) = {:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5}

h = {"item_1"=>{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5}}
g = {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>10}
g[:name]=>g = item_2=>{:name=>"item_2", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>10}

h = {"item_1"=>{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5},
     "item_2"=>{:name=>"item_2", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>10}}
g = {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>2, :unit_price=>10}
g[:name]=>g = item_2=>{:name=>"item_2", :qty=>2, :unit_price=>10}
Defer to block to calc value of key item_2
o = {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>10}
n = {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>2, :unit_price=>10}
{ qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty] } = {:qty=>5}
o.merge(qty: o[:qty] + n[:qty]) = {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>5, :unit_price=>10}

Value of h returned = 
  {"item_1"=>{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5},
   "item_2"=>{:name=>"item_2", :qty=>5, :unit_price=>10}}
h.values = [{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5},
            {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>5, :unit_price=>10}]
```

Notice that `update`'s block is not consulted when the first and third elements of `items` are passed to the outer block. That is because the `h` does not yet contain the key `g[:name]`.

See [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap).

Comment: @Ben, many thanks for catching my error. Note only did it mutate `items`, but it was just wrong. I've made a needed fix and will elaborate. Incidentally, when I offer a solution that mutates the input and the OP has been silent about whether that is permitted (which I rarely do) I follow what I think is general practice at SO of pointing out in my answer that it mutates the input.

Comment: Thanks for the simpler and well-explained solution.

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
items = [
  {name: 'item_1', qty: 1, unit_price: 5},
  {name: 'item_1', qty: 2, unit_price: 5},
  {name: 'item_2', qty: 3, unit_price: 10},
  {name: 'item_2', qty: 2, unit_price: 10}
]
```

code

```
result = items.group_by { |item| item[:name] }
              .values
              .map do |arr|
  arr.reduce do |h1, h2|
    h1.merge(h2) do |k1, v1, v2|
      k1.eql?(:qty) ? v1 + v2 : v1
    end
  end
end
```

output

```
[{:name=>"item_1", :qty=>3, :unit_price=>5}, {:name=>"item_2", :qty=>5, :unit_price=>10}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses the double splat operator to duplicate the hash and set the qty to zero when first populating an entry for the name in the accumulator hash.

```
items.reduce({}) do |acc, val|
  acc[val[:name]] ||= {**val, qty: 0} # initialise entry in accumulator hash for name
  acc[val[:name]][:qty] += val[:qty]  # add quantity to entry in accumulator hash
  acc
end.values
```

Comment: That's quite cool! I hadn't thought of the double splat as being so versatile.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from here and find an optimal solution

```
items.inject([]) do |acc, el|
  item_exists = acc.any?  {|e| e[:name].eql? el[:name] }
  item_exists ? acc.find {|e| e[:name].eql? el[:name] }[:qty] += el[:qty]  : acc << el
  acc
end
```